# Pandas replace values in a dataframe with column, row condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like this

```
          a    b    c    d
a;b;c;d   nan  nan  nan  nan
    a;b   nan  nan  nan  nan
    a;c   nan  nan  nan  nan
    b;c   nan  nan  nan  nan
  b;c;d   nan  nan  nan  nan
```

I want to make this into

```
          a    b    c    d
a;b;c;d   o    o    o    o
    a;b   o    o    x    x
    a;c   o    x    o    x
    b;c   x    o    o    x
  b;c;d   x    o    o    o
```

'o' and 'x's are determined by column and row conditions.
For example, cell (a;b, b) is turned into 'o' because in a;b, there is b.
And cell (b;c;d, a) is turned into 'x' because in b;c;d, there is no a.

The original dataframe is much larger, so I want the solution to be applied for other similar circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the idea here is to make a dataframe with binaries value from the index and change the value of 0 and 1 accordingly

use `str.get_dummies()`+`pd.DataFrame()`+`replace()`:

```
out=(pd.DataFrame(df.index.str.get_dummies(';').tolist(),columns=df.columns,index=df.index)
       .replace({1:'o',0:'x'}))
```

OR

Another way via `explode()`+`pd.crosstab()`:

```
s=df.reset_index()['index'].str.split(';').explode()
out=pd.crosstab(s.index,s).replace({1:'o',0:'x'})
out.index=df.index
out.columns.names=[None]
```

output of `out`:

```
           a    b   c   d
a;b;c;d     o   o   o   o
a;b         o   o   x   x
a;c         o   x   o   x
b;c         x   o   o   x
b;c;d       x   o   o   o
```

Answer (score -1):

- the values in the index define the columns and values
- `reset_index()` to make index a column so `apply()` can be used
- restore index after extraction has been done

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO("""          a    b    c    d
a;b;c;d   nan  nan  nan  nan
    a;b   nan  nan  nan  nan
    a;c   nan  nan  nan  nan
    b;c   nan  nan  nan  nan
  b;c;d   nan  nan  nan  nan"""),sep="\s+",)

df.reset_index()["index"].apply(
    lambda s: pd.Series({t: "x" for t in s.split(";")})
).fillna("o").set_index(df.index)
```

|  | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a;b;c;d | x | x | x | x |
| a;b | x | x | o | o |
| a;c | x | o | x | o |
| b;c | o | x | x | o |
| b;c;d | o | x | x | x |

Answer (score -1):

Here is my simple solution.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':["nan","nan","nan","nan","nan"],
               'b':["nan","nan","nan","nan","nan"],
               'c':["nan","nan","nan","nan","nan"],
               'd':["nan","nan","nan","nan","nan"]})

df.index =['a;b;c;d','a;b','a;c','b;c','b;c;d']
for row in df.itertuples():
for column in df.columns():
    if column in row.Index:
        df[column][row.Index] = 'o'
    else:
        df[column][row.Index] = 'x'

print(df)
```

Output:

[image]